# failed to encode and run yahoo query in Java

Tags: java

Basically, I am trying to encode and run the following yahoo query **using Java**. I have multiple threads in this website already. Yet, I am still not getting this correct.

```
    String url = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?"; 
    String yql_query = "select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol=\"0001.hk\"";
    String yql_query1 = yql_query.replace(" ", "%20");
    String fullUrl = url + URLEncoder.encode(yql_query1, "UTF-8") + "&format=json";
    System.out.println(fullUrl);
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(fullUrl).get();
```

The resulting query looks like this in the console:

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?select%2520*%2520from%2520yahoo.finance.quotes%2520where%2520symbol%3D%220001.hk%22&format=json
```

Now, I am totally new to this concept of API. I would like to know do I need to have set up **OAuth** before running the code above ? And how do I get the above code to work?

Comment: If you run your query in a browser, you get the below error:
`{"error":{"lang":"en-US","description":"You must specify a yql statement (q=) to execute"}}` ...

Comment: Yes I know that but i dont know how to resolve it.

Comment: check my answer then

Comment: Did you figure it out? Did my answer help you?

Comment: Sorry it doesn't. I added it in but it still gave me an error.

Comment: It's a different error or the same?

Answer (score 0):

If you run your query in a browser, you get the below error:

> {"error":{"lang":"en-US","description":"You must specify a yql
>   statement (q=) to execute"}}

So add "q=" just before the select

```
String yql_query = "q=" + "select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol=\"0001.hk\"";
```